# Escape double quotes with variable inside HTML echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, addslashes

For a variable inside a echo that contains HTML, where would I add slashes to escape the double quotes?

Example:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=".$row['id']." />";
```

This part:

```
value=".$row['id']."
```

Comment: With `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Some tips on outputting HTML with PHP:

1. Use single quotes so that you don't have to escape the double quotes (when using echo),
2. Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to properly escape any "rogue" values you may have.

Example using `echo`:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="', htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
```

Or `printf()`:

```
printf('<input type="hidden" name="id" value="%s" />', 
    htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
);
```

Or, in HTML mode:

```
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
<?php
```

Comment: FYI, the defaults for `htmlspecialchars` should suffice for a double-quoted `value` attribute so you can safely leave off the second and third arguments.

Comment: @Phil The defaults *should* suffice, but they historically didn't :)

Comment: Biggest problem with PHP is its *history* :)

Comment: `the defaults for htmlspecialchars should suffice for a double-quoted value` Nope, at least for me I need a `ENT_QUOTES` for `htmlspecialchars` to work

Answer (score 4):

Use `htmlentities`:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"".htmlentities($row['id'])."\" />";
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to answer to the OP. (where the question seems to be how to escape the html attribute value)

Comment: Fair point - I misread the question originally. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

How about use single quotes so you don't have to escape any quotes.
Like so:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />';
```